# VK Api - Application authorization failed: refresh service token

Tags: vk

When backend server call /method/secure.checkToken Api, it return a error message.

```
{
    "error_code":28,
    "error_msg":"Application authorization failed: refresh service token"....
}
```

What's mean about error_code 28?
is it mean my service token error?

Answer (score 0):

This means that your application's access key is invalid

https://vk.com/dev/errors

This April VK changed access to the API. Now all requests must be signed with an application access key.